# Check if select option class already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append a select element dynamically in html and when any option is changed in any of the select then I want to check if that option is already selected in any of the existing select elements.

For that I am using a class for each select option and when an option is changed in any select, then check if that class of selected option exists already.

I'm using following code but I'm unable to figure out how to check each select to see if the same option is selected.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list">

</div>

<div class="hide">
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option class="a" value="">A</option>
    <option class="b" value="">B</option>
    <option class="c" value="">C</option>
    <option class="d" value="">D</option>
  </select>
</div>

 <button class="add" type="add">Add</button>
```

**Js:**

```
$('.add').on('click', function(e){
    $('.list').append($('.hide').html());

});


$(document).on('change', '.list select', function(){

var cls = $(this).find(':selected').attr('class');

if ($('.list .'+cls).length > 0) {
    alert('It exists');
}


});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vtzor9Ld/

Comment: In what way does it not work? For me the jsfiddle seems to work as you describe it should work

Comment: @JoelPeltonen it doesn't work in that it includes the currently selected.  Click add once, select an option, alert shows.  But "doesnt seem to work" isn't the most detailed diagnostic... (Sam) see https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: @JoelPeltonen sorry, I thought i had explained the required functionality that i was trying to achieve, and the if condition wasn't able to get that. There is demo link included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be fixed with this line:

```
if ($(`.list option.${cls}:selected`).length > 1) {
    console.log('It exists');
}
```

You'll want to test for more than 1 occurrence, (rather than 0), and you'll want to test the selected options only for matching class

Here's another method that finds the occurrences one by one in case that was useful information.

```js
$('.add').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.list').append($('.hide').html());
});

$(document).on('change', '.list select', function() {
  var cls = $(this).find(':selected').attr('class');
  $('.list select').not($(this)).find('option:selected').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass(cls)) console.log("Matching class on select # " + (i + 1))
  })
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="hide">
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option class="a" value="">A</option>
    <option class="b" value="">B</option>
    <option class="c" value="">C</option>
    <option class="d" value="">D</option>
  </select>
</div> <button class="add" type="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: What's the problem in OPs example? What have you changed? And why?

Comment: It's different, I am writing that now

Answer (score 1):

You could try to loop over option and check it one by one with the class whether it is the same or not.

```
  $(document).on('change', '.list select', function(){    
         var cls = $(this).find(':selected').attr('class');
        
         if ($('.list .' + cls).length > 0) {   
    
         $('.list select').not(this).each(function(i) {
              var value = $(this).find(':selected').attr('class');  
              
              if (typeof  value != 'undefined' && cls == value)
                     console.log('it matched ' + i);    
            
            });
        }       
    
    });
```